# Overriding @media CSS with the iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, css, html-email

The issue I'm encountering is text gets cut off in this HTML email on Android (4.0 with Samsung Galaxy).

I've used @media queries to address this, but they adversely affect the iPhone, scaling down the width too much. I'm trying to cancel out the `width: 300px !important;` just for the iPhone with no luck.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Current @Media:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: .75) {
  /* CSS for Low-density screens goes here *
   * Ex: HTC Evo, HTC Incredible, Nexus One */
   /* Styles */
      table[class="table"], td[class="cell"] {

width: 300px !important;
}
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1) and (max-device-width: 768px) {
  /* CSS for Medium-density screens goes here *
   * Ex: Samsung Ace, Kindle Fire, Macbook Pro *
   * max-device-width added so you don't target laptops and desktops */
   /* Styles */
      table[class="table"], td[class="cell"] {
width: 300px !important;

}
}


/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
    @media
    only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
      table[class="table"], td[class="cell"] {
          width:auto !important;
}

}
```

Without Media query Android text gets cut off:

[image: Without Media query Android text gets cut off]

Media query also shrinks the width of td/table to 300px on the iPhone adversely affecting its display

[image: With Media query iPhone shrinks the width of td/table to 300px]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your CSS definition that you want to be applied is more specific;

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
    .container table[class="table"], .table td[class="cell"] {
        width: auto !important;
    }
}
```

Where `.container` is a hypothetical container.

Comment: I don't believe it's issue of specificity because I tried that and what happens is then the problem is flipped -- the iPhone is fixed, but Android text gets cut off again.

Comment: @jsuissa I meant be more specific **inside** your iPhone-only `@media`. See edit.

Comment: Got it. So I tried that and it did what I described. I think that means that the issue is the iPhone media query is also affecting the Android device?

Comment: @jsuissa Not precisely. The issue is that both rules are equally specific (they both have `!important`, and the same selector) so the browser wouldn't know that it should override. The more specific rules force it to override the less-specific ones. If this worked for you, don't forget to accept this answer!

Comment: No luck. Even changing the specificity didn't work. I believe the problem is my 'iPhone' specific media query is also affecting Android, not just the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

As the alternative to "-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5" I suspect you want "-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1". I don't know what browsers will do with Media Queries that are neither "min-" nor "max-" (such as "-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1"); I suspect some browsers will interpret the Media Query to mean equality, but many will just barf and always say the query was false.

Does your browser perchance put error messages about Media Queries it doesn't understand into the "Error Console"?

The case of a handheld device reporting density 1 but a very large width like 800 (the "viewport" width) will sometimes occur. Your current code seems to send *no* CSS to such devices, which I doubt is what you intend. Having a particular Media Query (such as max-device-width:) on some parts of your CSS but not others is often a hint some edge cases aren't being considered.

Answer (score 0):

try playing with `max-width` and `min-width`, to satisfy both androids and iphones. It worked for me.